# How do I calculate the Average marks?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm making a histogram which collects the results of student marks and displays which marks are in a certain range e.g 0-29 or 70-100.

I'm trying to figure out how I can edit my code so that I can calculate the average mark. I know the average mark is calculated by adding all numbers and dividing by the amount of numbers but I'm having trouble implementing that into my program.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int studentMark = 0;

    // ranges from (1)0-29, (2)30-39, (3)40-69, (4)70-100 (4 ranges)

    int firstRange = 0;         // (1)
    int secondRange = 0;        // (2)
    int thirdRange = 0;         // (3)
    int fourthRange = 0;        // (4)

    // counts all 'mark' attempts (except anything > 100)

    int numberOfStudents = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
        System.out.println("Enter a mark from 1-100: ");
        studentMark = input.nextInt();

    if (studentMark < 29) 
    {
        firstRange++;
        numberOfStudents++;
    }

    if ((studentMark > 29) && (studentMark <= 39)) 
    {
        secondRange++;
        numberOfStudents++;
    }

    if ((studentMark <= 69) && (studentMark > 39)) 
    {
        thirdRange++;
        numberOfStudents++;
    }

    if ((studentMark <= 100) && (studentMark > 69))
    {
        fourthRange++;
        numberOfStudents++;
    }


    }while ((studentMark <= 100))


    System.out.println("\nResults: \n");
    System.out.println("Number of students in total: " + numberOfStudents);
    System.out.println("\nStudents who ranged from 0-29: " + firstRange );
    System.out.println("Students who ranged from 30-39: " + secondRange);
    System.out.println("Students who ranged from 40-69: " + thirdRange);
    System.out.println("Students who ranged from 70-100: " + fourthRange);

    }
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: I rolled back your last edit, because you replaced the code part with code which is unreleated to the question. Please avoid doing that and please don't remove the code part altogether, like you did in your other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to counts for each range, you need to keep total of all grades and total count (or just add individual range totals)

Comment: Perfectly said. I created a variable called `keepMark` and performed `keepMark = keepMark + studentMark;` at the end of each statement. Of course now I can just divide the total by `numberOfStudents`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The border tests are redondant and at least two cases aren't treated:
- rank = 29
- rank < 0

Below a simplified code:

```
        // ranges from (1)0-29, (2)30-39, (3)40-69, (4)70-100 (4 ranges)
    final int[] roofs = new int[] {30, 40, 70, 101};
    final int[] compters = new int[roofs.length];
    final double[] sums = new double[roofs.length];
    final double[] means = new double[roofs.length];

    final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a mark from 0-100: ");
        final int studentMark = input.nextInt();
        int index = -1;

        if (studentMark < 0) {
            continue; // here to be ignored
        } else if (studentMark < roofs[0]) {
            index = 0;
        } else if (studentMark < roofs[1]) {
            index = 1;
        } else if (studentMark < roofs[2]) {
            index = 2;
        } else if (studentMark < roofs[3]) {
            index = 3;
        } else {
            break;
        }
        compters[index]++;
        sums[index] += studentMark;
    } while (true);
    input.close();

    final int numberOfStudents = Arrays.stream(compters).sum();
    IntStream.range(0, roofs.length).forEach(i -> means[i] = sums[i] / compters[i]);
```